# Connect Arduino MQTT client with Node JS MQTT server

Tags: c++, c, node.js, arduino, mqtt

I'm creating a home automaton system using Node js and Arduino. Have a problem. I have to use MQTT (http://mqtt.org/). So i used MQTT server in my node server and now i want to use MQTT in my Arduino. It;s written in C. So can I use and connect Node MQTT links with C language ( Arduino) links ?

Node MQTT : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is a network communications protocol, it really doesn't care what language the broker or clients are written in.

As long as both the broker and client conform to the protocol, it will not matter.